# Change default starter js ( server.js) for node on openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

How can I change the name of default starter script for node on openshift ?
default starter script is server.js.

I saw a thread on [openshift forum](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/nodejs-on-openshift-you-bet-your-javascript), however it is difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the package.json file, and you should see this:

```
  "main": "server.js"
```

Comment: hi seawolf, i am using express for my project and the package.json doesn't have this key. Is it possible to add the main key ? if possible then where should i add that ?

Comment: I have it at the root level, along with 'name', 'engines', 'dependencies' and some others.